# Fixing source folders in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I was able to fork a project on GitHub and get it setup in eclipse, but I have a problem with the source folders. Basically, it's putting all the packages at the root of the source folder rather than building the proper hierarchy. Here is a screenshot that shows the issue I am having:
[image: the problem]

I want it to combine all of the packages in to a top level com package, and then under that is the sk89q package, and then under that there should be the bukkit, jnbt, util, worldedit, etc packages. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try step:

1. from "Package Explorer",
2. click  down arrow
3. select "Package Presentation"
4. select "Hierarchical"